# Proof that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^{2}}$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I want to come up with a good argument as to why $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^{2}}$ DNE. Here is my attempt.

Proof by Contradiction: Suppose $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^{2}}=L$ where $L\in(-\infty,\infty)$.

Well for any $x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$, $0<\frac{1}{x^{2}}<1$.

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^{2}}=L\implies0<\frac{1}{x^{2}}\leq L$ for any $x\in[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$.

So, $0<\frac{1}{x^{2}}<1+L$ for any $x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$.

Let's consider $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+L}}\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ $[0<1+L]$.

Then,
$\frac{1}{\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+L}}\big)^{2}}<1+L\implies(\sqrt{1+L})^{2}<1+L\implies|1+L|<1+L$

$\implies 1+L<1+L$.

A contradiction. Thus, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^{2}}$ DNE.

Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I do need to exclude $\{0\}$ in all of this! Should I include $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{x^{2}}=L$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{1}{x^{2}}=L$?

Comment: The graph of $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$ will show you that limit of  $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$ is $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. Of course, you can proof that

Comment: Well, if we assume that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^{2}}=L$, then $1\leq\frac{1}{x^{2}}\leq L$ in the interval $[-1,1]/\{0\}$. Wouldn't that imply that $0<\frac{1}{x^{2}}\leq L$?

Comment: Drawing a graph is a nice way to visualize the whole situation.  I suggest reading [this question about explaining epsilon-delta to biology/chemistry students](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1131391/290189), to which I provided an answer with illustrations like $$\Large\bbox[5px, #FDF, border: 1px solid black]{
y = A \quad \begin{array}{cc} \hline
\updownarrow \epsilon & \phantom{\Rule{6em}{1ex}{0px}} \\ \hdashline
\updownarrow \epsilon & \\ \hline
\end{array}
} \tag{H-strip} \label{fig:hstrip}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to prove the claim by contradiction, but with no $\varepsilon-\delta$ analysis, which I use when I am really desperate.

Assume $$\lim_{x\to 0}{1\over x^2}=L$$ Then
$$1=\lim_{x\to 0}x^2{1\over x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}x^2\lim_{x\to 0}{1\over x^2}=0\cdot L=0$$

Comment: That's a really nice one!

Answer (score 2):

> $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^{2}}=L\implies0<\frac{1}{x^{2}}\leq L$ for any $x\in[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$.

This line is incorrect.  Say $-h^2 \to 0 \ge 0$ as $h \to 0$, but $-h^2 \le 0$.

Limits preserves monotonicity.  That is, if $f(x) \ge 0$ on an open interval containing a point $a$, and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L \in \Bbb{R}$, then $L \ge 0$.
However, the converse is incorrect.  I've given a counterexample above.

It's nice to start with a proof by contradiction, but I suggest that you use the definition ($\epsilon$-$\delta$ criterion) of the limit with $\epsilon = 1$ to establish a $\delta$-neighbourhood $(-\delta,\delta)$ about $x = 0$ so that for all $0 < |x|<\delta$, $$\left|\frac{1}{x^2} - L\right| < \epsilon = 1.$$
$$ L - 1 < \frac{1}{x^2} < L + 1. $$
In particular, $$x > \frac{1}{\sqrt{L+1}} \label{wrong1} \tag{$\star$}$$
Here, both $\delta$ and $L$ exist, and they come from your hypothesis (to be rejected by contradition later).
Note that the quantifier in front of "$0 < |x| < \delta$" is "for all", so you can choose some small $x_0\in (-\delta,\delta) \setminus \{0\}$ so that \eqref{wrong1} is violated, say $x_0 = \min\left\{\frac\delta2, \frac{1}{2\sqrt{L+1}}\right\}$.
This proves that the limit $L$ doesn't exists.

Comment: Great explanation! I did feel that line was a bit off, so that's why I asked for clarification here. If I can, I love to prove these whenever I see them in a calculus textbook (without having to rely too heavily on analysis).